# Why does the stack pointer need to be set for EL1 configuration?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, qemu, bare-metal

Im studying some bare metal code for raspberry Pi, in particular this [code](https://github.com/eggman/raspberrypi/blob/master/qemu-raspi3/int01/boot.S) for a QEMU emulation. It goes down from EL3 to EL1, but why need the sp_el1 need to be set for EL1 configuration from EL2 and again in EL1 the sp is set? If i remove any of the both sp assingments in the code it just wont make interrupts.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the AArch64 architecture there are four physical stack pointer registers: SP_EL0, SP_EL1, SP_EL2 and SP_EL3. When executing at EL0, the "SP" register which is the currently-in-use stack pointer is always SP_EL0. At higher exception levels, there is a state bit PSTATE.SPSel that defines what "SP" is:

- if SPSel is 1 then execution uses the SP_ELx for that exception level
- if SPSel is 0 then it uses SP_EL0.

SPSel can be set directly by an MSR, but it is also set when you do an exception return, according to the value in SPSR_ELx. On reset, SPSel is 1.

In your code, the code at EL2 sets SP_EL1, but when it drops to EL1 it uses an SPSR_EL2 value that selects "EL1t", which means "EL1, using SP_EL0" (as opposed to EL1h). So when EL1 is running it is using SP_EL0, which hasn't yet been initialized by anybody. The "mov sp, x1" is initializing SP_EL0.

When you take an interrupt to EL1, the CPU will go to EL1h, which is why SP_EL1 needs to be set up as well as SP_EL0.